# Why am I getting a NoneType for Allowed Host in Django-Environ when I set allowed host?

Tags: django, wagtail, django-settings, django-environ

The settings code is

```
import os
import environ

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False))

environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))
```

the allowed host is written as

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get("ALLOWED_HOSTS").split(',')
```

the .env file has ALLOWED_HOSTS as

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
```

why am I getting the fail code

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

when I run the command

```
docker-compose up --build -d --remove-orphans
```

Comment: Don't know about `environ`, seems to work fine with `dotenv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it in the wrong way -

1. the env value should be comma-separated

   ```
   # env file

   ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost,127.0.0.1,[::1]
   ```
2. Access the env variable using `env` (instance of `Env(...)`)

   ```py
   # settings.py

   env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False))

   environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = env.list('ALLOWED_HOSTS')
   # or
   # ALLOWED_HOSTS = env('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=list)
   ```

Comment: Your answer is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're experiencing this error for two reasons:

---

**(1)** Because the ALLOWED_HOSTS inside your **.env** file aren't actually separated by commas. See below for current state and potential fix:

**Current .env**

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
```

**Corrected .env**

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

---

**(2)** You are importing your ALLOWED_HOSTS strangely into **settings.py**, and can do so more standardly as below:

**Corrected settings.py**

```py
import os
import environ

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

env = environ.Env(
    DEBUG=(bool, False),
    ALLOWED_HOSTS=(list, [])  ## Add this!
)

environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = env.list('ALLOWED_HOSTS')  ## Change your code to this!
```